# voltDB on window

Tags: php, database, linux, wamp, voltdb

I am looking to set up VoltDB on the Windows platform.

Has anyone implemented it previously? Please share your experience.

If there is any issue with installing on the Windows platform, please help me understand how to implement it on the Linux platform. I have read some VoltDB documentation, but I can't understand the method to install it on Linux. I am new in Linux and VoltDB also.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post. But just wanted to update this with how VoltDB can now be run on Windows using Docker. More information can be found on our [VoltDB community page](http://voltdb.com/community/demo#windows).

Answer (score 0):

VoltDB does not currently run on Windows.  The Enterprise Edition runs on 64-bit Linux.  The Community Edition runs on 64-bit Linux or on MAC OS X.  You can run VoltDB within a Linux VM on a Windows computer.

The installation instructions are covered in [Using VoltDB](https://voltdb.com/docs/UsingVoltDB/): [Ch. 2: Installing VoltDB](https://voltdb.com/docs/UsingVoltDB/ChapGetStarted.php)

The installation is minimally just unpacking the tar.gz file.  You can add the /bin directory to your path, but that's not required.  Before you start the database, you need to compile your schema into a catalog file, and provide it as a parameter on the command line when you run the "voltdb" script to start the database.  This is explained in more detail in the documentation.

If you are installing from the source code on Github, you first need to run a build.  There are instructions to do this in Github on the [project wiki](https://github.com/VoltDB/voltdb/wiki/Building-VoltDB).  You can build it on 64-bit Linux or Mac.